# Jetpack Compose custom layout clicks don't work

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I created my own class called MyInputRow.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyInputRow(
    title: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    bgColor: Color,
    icon: Painter,
    clickAction: Unit
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(6.dp)
            .background(color = bgColor)
            .clickable { clickAction },
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    )
    {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(6.dp)
                .wrapContentWidth(Alignment.Start),
            text = title,
        )
        Image(
            painter = icon,
            contentDescription = "icon"
        )
    }
}
```

But, this clickAction does not work.
Specifically, clickAction is called for some reason when the screen is displayed, and clickAction is not called when Row is clicked.
It is called as follows.

```kotlin
class AddActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        setContent {
            MyTheme {
                    ...
                    AddMain()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun AddMain() {
        BarcodeLayout()
    },
}

@Composable
fun BarcodeLayout() {
    Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Text(text = {...})

        MyInputRow(
            title = ...,
            bgColor = ...,
            icon = ...,
            clickAction = scanBarcode()
        )
    }
}

fun scanBarcode() {
 Timber.d("call scanBarcode")
}
```

I don't know why. Please help me.

Comment: `clickAction: Unit` -> `clickAction: () -> Unit`

Comment: Thank you for answering. After the change, clickAction is no longer called without permission. But,Clicking MyInputRow still does not call clickAction.

Comment: You need to actually call it e.g. `.clickable { clickAction() }`, or pass directly `.clickable(clickAction)`.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I was able to call it safely!

Comment: You're welcome. These are Kotlin basics that have nothing to do with Compose. You can delete this question as it won't help anyone else - for the same reason they will have other parts of the application not work, so they can't find it by question title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 options you can try.

Option 1:

`.clickable { clickAction() }`

or Option 2:

`.clickable(clickAction)`